Wrong icon size in UIButton created with UIButton.Configuration and .png image
I have created two sets of UIButtons, with regular constructors (top StackVew on the attached image) and with UIButton.Configuration (the bottom StackView).
Both have icons created from a .png file.
The bottom buttons have icons that don't fit inside the button size and seem to be rendered in native .png size. Even the contentMode is set to .scaleAspectFill
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

How to make the icon fit inside button size for buttons created with UIButton.Configuration?
env: XCode 15.4, Simulator iOS 17.5
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    let stackView1 = UIStackView()
    stackView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView1.distribution = .fill
    stackView1.alignment = .fill
    stackView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
     
    let stackView2 = UIStackView()
    stackView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView2.distribution = .fill
    stackView2.alignment = .fill
    stackView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(stackView1)
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
     
    view.addSubview(stackView2)
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView2.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1.centerYAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
     
    stackView1.addArrangedSubview(makeButton(backgroundColor: .red))
    stackView1.addArrangedSubview(makeButton(backgroundColor: .blue))
    stackView1.addArrangedSubview(makeButton(backgroundColor: .yellow))
    stackView1.addArrangedSubview(makeButton(backgroundColor: .cyan))
     
    stackView2.addArrangedSubview(makeButtonWithConfiguration(backgroundColor: .red))
    stackView2.addArrangedSubview(makeButtonWithConfiguration(backgroundColor: .blue))
    stackView2.addArrangedSubview(makeButtonWithConfiguration(backgroundColor: .yellow))
    stackView2.addArrangedSubview(makeButtonWithConfiguration(backgroundColor: .cyan))
  }
  func makeButton(backgroundColor: UIColor) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "apple.png"), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return button
  }
   
  func makeButtonWithConfiguration(backgroundColor: UIColor) -> UIButton {
    var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    configuration.image = UIImage(named: "apple.png")
    configuration.contentInsets = .zero
      
    let button = UIButton(configuration: configuration)
    button.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
     
    return button
  }
}



When using UIButton.Configuration the image is not resized to the button (or vice versa). UIKit expects you to use an appropriately sized image.

Correction ... if you have not set a width constraint (or, as in your example, you've used a stack view to control the button size), the button will auto-size its width based on the size of the image. Likewise with height constraint. In any case, though, the image will not resize based on the button size.

@DonMag thanks for the reply,
But how do we deal with it if different screen resolution support is required?

Petro - that's a good question. I get the impression that Apple assumes SF Symbols will be used as images for buttons using UIButton.Configuration. So, we can either use Symbols, or... scale images on-the-fly, or... continue to use the non-Configuration style buttons.

@DonMag Agree. But in this case, why did Apple make some parts of the old Button API deprecated, such as "'imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0".
To overcome this deprecation, we must use UIButton.Configuration, which breaks old API functionality, eg with icons, described in the question above.

Curiously, if we read Apple's docs...
UIButton.Configuration

Overview
You can configure and update a button with a UIButton.Configuration. A button configuration contains all the customization options available with other methods, such as setTitle(_:for:), and can serve as a replacement for those methods. Alternatively, you can use a configuration in combination with these other methods and adopt new button behaviors and appearance without rewriting your customized UIButton code.

UIButton

Specify edge insets
Use insets to add or remove space around the content in your custom or system buttons. You can specify separate insets for your button’s title (titleEdgeInsets), image (imageEdgeInsets), and both the title and image together (contentEdgeInsets). When applied, insets affect the corresponding content rectangle of the button, which the Auto Layout engine uses to determine the button’s position.

Of course, if we follow any of those Edge Insets links, we get pages stating they are Deprecated, with no equivalent properties or methods for .configuration!
Note that the deprecation notes state: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration.
I don't work for Apple, so this is speculation, but as I said in my comments "I get the impression that Apple assumes SF Symbols will be used as images for buttons using UIButton.Configuration." And, we can create our own custom Symbols.
So, if we want/need to use a bitmap image for a button...

size the UIImage ahead of time or on-the-fly, or
use Edge Insets for now, and update the code when they stop working, or
use a UIImageView with touch/tap handling

